# Find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying $|z| = 1$ and $\left| \tfrac{z}{\bar{z}} + \tfrac{\bar{z}}{z} \right| = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find all complex numbers $z$ satisfying the following conditions: $$|z| = 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \left| \dfrac{z}{\bar{z}} + \dfrac{\bar{z}}{z} \right| = 1 .$$ Here, $|\cdot|$ means the norm.

On the right side I do,

$$ |z^2 + \bar{z}^2|= z\bar{z}$$

but I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $|z| = 1$, we may write it in polar form as $$z = e^{i \theta} .$$ Then, $\bar{z} = e^{-i \theta}$ and so the second equation becomes
$$\left|e^{2 i \theta} + e^{-2 i \theta}\right| = 1,$$
but this equation can be written in terms of the cosine function using the identity (or if you prefer, definition)
$$\cos \alpha = \tfrac{1}{2}(e^{i \alpha} + e^{-i \alpha}).$$

Comment: Using this I have $| 2 \cos{2\theta} | = 1$, then, $| \cos{2\theta} | = \frac{1}{2}$. It's Ok? Because I think that there are more solutions. In final I have $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6} $.

Comment: What are all the values of $\alpha$ such that $\cos \alpha = \pm \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: You want to say $\cos{2\alpha} = \pm \frac{1}{2}$. Or not?

Comment: Well, for $\alpha = 2 \theta$, this is $\cos 2 \theta = \pm \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since $z\bar z=|z|^2$, your equation is equivalent at
$$|z^2+\bar z^2|=1$$